# jQuery Format Time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery script that receives a string in milliseconds inside a parameter, like this:

```
params.tweetDate='77771564221';
```

What I need to do is to create a jQuery function that will be able to format this milliseconds string in a USA time, like `10.00 AM` or `10.00 PM`.

Is there a jQuery function that is able to do this?

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: what does tweetDate represent? is it milliseconds since midnight or since 1969 (I think this is where Date will start counting from if provided by milliseconds) ??

Comment: @redmoon7777: The normal values are either seconds or milliseconds since The Epoch (Jan 1, 1970 at midnight GMT). I noted in my answer that the above appears to be neither, as using it as milliseconds since The Epoch gives us a date in June 1972 (long before Twitter), and using it as seconds since The Epoch gives us a date in June 4434. :-) So the first thing will indeed be to find out what that value represents.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is Date object in pure javascript, no jQuery needed.
http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/date.shtml

Example:

```
var time = new Date(params.tweetDate),
h = time.getHours(), // 0-24 format
m = time.getMinutes();
// next just convert to AM/PM format (check if h > 12)
```

Comment: Would you please provide an example?

Comment: Yuri: *"(check if h > 12)"* No, it's `h >= 12` (12 is 12:00 p.m. [noon], 0 is 12 a.m. [midnight]).

Comment: This works, but you need to pad a zero for values 0-9 for true 24hour format.

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no jQuery function for this. You can use

- JavaScript's own `Date` object, using the `getHours()` and `getMinutes()` functions, handling the AM/PM thing yourself (e.g., hours >= 12 is PM), padding out the minutes with a leading 0 if minutes is less than 10, etc. Also note that if hours is 0, you want to make it 12 (because when using the AM/PM style, you write midnight as "12:00 AM", not "0:00 AM").
- [DateJS](http://datejs.com), an add-on library that does a huge amount of date stuff (although sadly it's not actively maintained)
- [PrettyDate](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-pretty-date/) from John Resig (the creator of jQuery)

To use just about any of those, first you have to turn that "milliseconds" value into a `Date` object. If it's really a "milliseconds" value, then first you parse the string into a number via `parseInt(str, 10)` and then use `new Date(num)` to create the `Date` object representing that point in time. So:

```
var dt = new Date (parseInt(params.tweetDate, 10));
```

However, the value you've quoted, which you said is a milliseconds value, seems a bit odd — normally it's milliseconds since The Epoch (Jan 1, 1970), which is what JavaScript uses, but `new Date(parseInt("77771564221", 10))` gives us a date in June 1972, long before Twitter. It's not *seconds* since The Epoch either (a fairly common Unix convention), because `new Date(parseInt("77771564221", 10) * 1000)` gives us a date in June 4434. So the first thing to find out is what that value actually represents, milliseconds since *when*. Then adjust it so it's milliseconds since The Epoch, and feed it into `new Date()` to get the object.

Comment: How do this work with my milliseconds string? I am a little confused.

Comment: @DiegoP.: Ah, sorry, left that out. Updated. The value you've quoted is a bit odd, though.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function for you:

```
function timeFormatter(dateTime){
var date = new Date(dateTime);
if (date.getHours()>=12){
    var hour = parseInt(date.getHours()) - 12;
    var amPm = "PM";
} else {
    var hour = date.getHours(); 
    var amPm = "AM";
}
var time = hour + ":" + date.getMinutes() + " " + amPm;
console.log(time);
return time;
}
```

You may call the function in any approach like:

```
var time = timeFormatter(parseInt("2345678998765"));
```

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/): this is a jquery plugin used exactly for this purposes.

Comment: I do not understand it very well. Could you please provide a sample of how it will work with a milliseconds string?

Comment: +1 but this seems to be more about using the "ago" style rather than just formatting in the U.S. time style as the OP requested.

Answer (score 1):

Using T.J.'s solution this is what I ended up with.

```
var date = new Date(parseInt("77771564221", 10));
var result = new Array();
result[0] = $.datepicker.formatDate('DD, M, d, yy', date);
result[1] = ' ';
if (date.getHours() > 12) {
    result[2] = date.getHours() - 12;
} else if (date.getHours() == 0 ) {
    result[2] = "12";
} else {
    result[2] = date.getHours();
}
result[3] = ":"
result[4] = date.getMinutes();

if (date.getHours() > 12) {
    result[5] = " pm";
} else {
    result[5] = " am";
}

console.log(result.join(''));
```